# How to capture src and dst traffic (both directions) with tcpdump, with one command?

Tags: networking, rhel, tcpdump, wireshark, bonding

I am using RedHat (6.5) bonding and my active interface is `eth5`.

Running the following command, I'm not able to see the traffic originated by my NIC IP address:

```
tcpdump -i eth5 src host actual_ip_address_of_external_client
```

I'm only able to see the source traffic too, via the command below (using wireshark):

```
tcpdump -i eth5 src host actual_ip_address_of_external_client -w /tmp/<outputfile>
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Not 100% but I believe `tcpdump` supports the `or` operator

Comment: thanks could you please me sample syntax regarding my situation ? or what else do you recommended instead of tcpdump command? please clarify

Comment: you should probably do something like `tcpdump -i eth5 host <currentHost> or host <destinationHost>` Just as an example: `tcpdump -i eth5 host 192.168.122.23 or 192.168.122.25`.

Comment: So are you saying that, without `-w /tmp/<outputfile>`, tcpdump doesn't print traffic from the `actual_ip_address_of_external_client`, but if you add `-w /tmp/<outputfile>` to the command, making no change to the filter or the `-i` argument, and then read the file in Wireshark, you *do* see traffic from that address?

Comment: @GuyHarris as you said I have facing same issue. Also I can see external IP address of host  in wireshark  as [source] from address. otherwise if an external host (say 118.168.141.172) made a connection, I would like to capture the traffic. OK?

Answer (score 11):

To monitor traffic on both directions between `host_a` and `host_b` you can use:

```
# tcpdump -nli eth6 host host_a and host_b
```

Comment: thanks info I solved my issue e.g tcpdump -ni s0 vlan and host_a and host_b and tcp 80

Comment: sudo tcpdump -s 65535 -i eth0 host 10.78.5.118 and host 41.212.409.114 -w ssl.pcap